# Why in this php code the indexes ["name"],["price"] and ["id"] won't display any data?

Tags: php, sql

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT
   cart.id    cart_id,
   dkb.id     dkb_id,
   cdkb.id    cdkb_id,
   dbl.id     dbl_id,
   cart.*,
   dkb.*,
   cdkb.*,
   dbl.*
FROM
    cart

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
       ON ( cart.id = dkb.id
            AND dkb.id = '".$ids."' )

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbl
       ON ( dbl.id = dkb.id )

    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb
       ON ( cart.id = cdkb.id
            AND cdkb.id = '".$id."' )
WHERE
    cart.cookieId ='" . GetCartId() . "' ' ORDER BY cdkb.name AND dkb.name ASC");

$totalCost=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
// Increment the total cost of all items
$totalCost += ($row["qty"] * $row["price"]);?>

<select name="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" onChange="UpdateQty(this)">

<?php echo $row["name"]; ?></p></div>
```

In the above query and php script the $row["id"], $row["name"] and $row["price"] fields from cdkb, dkb and cart tables won't display in the nothing in the html code. Well at least the $row["name"] is not displaying the name of the item does not appear in the database with the query set up above. Does the SELECT clause has to do something with it? maybe there has not been a field assigned in the SELECT clause that might be producing that $row["name"] no to appear.

Last issue...Tuesday, February 16, 2009 PART2

------------EDITED PART2-------------------

$is= isset($_GET['is'])?(int) $_GET['is']:null;
$ic= isset($_GET['is'])?(int) $_GET['is']:null;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT
   cart.id    cart_id,
   dkb.id     dkb_id,
   cdkb.id    cdkb_id,
   dbl.id     dbl_id,

FROM
    cart

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
   ON ( cart.id = dkb.id and dkb.id = $is )

LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb
   on ( cart.id = cdkb.id and cdkb.id = $ic )
```

WHERE cart.id = 1" );

--Error message below is what Run SQL query/queries on database phpmyadming program is displaying of EDIT PART2--

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cart LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb ON (cart.id = dkb.i' at line 21

I have changed the fields as they have been aliases different but still displays the same error #1064 Don't see what's the SQL syntax error here help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have multiple columns that call "name"

in your select , add to the list of  fields :

```
cdkb.name as name1 ,dkb.name as name2 ....
```

and then `echo $row['name1']` ...

Comment: The aliases need to be use inside the query or just in the php code as you have it?

for example dkb.id as id1

LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
       ON ( cart.id = id1
            AND id1 = '".$ids."' )

Comment: The aliases have to be in the query. When you use the same field name in multiple tables in a query, and retrieve them using mysql_fetch_array(), you have to make sure that all those field names are unique, because they'll be used as the array keys in PHP. e.g. `Select table1.name, table2.name, table3.name...` will turn into `$row['name']` only. But if you do `select table1.name as firstname, table2.name.secondname, table3.thirdname...` will become `$row['firstname']`, `$row['secondname']`, etc...

Comment: What about if you have many fields on those three tables that you won't necessarily use in that query and code do you have to specify it any ways at the query?

Comment: Thank you Marc B i got that explanation still the error whenever I test the query like on phpmyadmin. There is an error that goes like.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cart LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb ON (cart.id = dkb.id' at line 21

Answer (score 0):

Using more than one star in SELECT-query - bad practice.
You can get conflict with column names and your code can become erroneous.